# powershell script to group files based on a particular piece of text in their name

Tags: powershell

I have a list of files in a directory like the below:

```
[fsfsd][sdsdfsa][fasfdasf][sdasdfsafsd].pdf
```

I want to group these by what is in the fourth set of brackets.

I have the below but am getting errors

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -file;
ForEach ($file in $files)
{
  $fileName = $file.BaseName;
  $folder = New-Item -type directory -name $fileName.Substring($fileName.indexOf("[")+1, $fileName.lastIndexOf("]"));
  Move-Item $file.FullName $folder.FullName;
}
```

This is the regex for getting the 4th set of text from the file

```regex
(?<=(\[.+\]){3}\[).+(?=\])
```

Error message below:

'''Exception calling "Substring" with "2" argument(s): "Index and length must refer to a location within the string. Parameter name: length" At line:4 char:3 + $folder = New-Item -type directory -name $fileName.Substring($fileN ... + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentOutOfRangeException'''

Comment: Please post the (full) error messages you're getting

Comment: Please click the _edit_ link below your question and insert the error message in the question. Comments are not meant for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find files with names like that and to be able to move them to a folder with name being the string between the square brackets of the 4th part, I would use

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Test' -File | 
    Where-Object { $_.BaseName -match '^(?:\[\w+\]){3}(?:\[(\w+)\])' } | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $destination = Join-Path -Path $_.DirectoryName -ChildPath $matches[1]
        if (!(Test-Path -Path $destination -PathType Container)) {
            $null = New-Item -Path $destination -ItemType Directory
        }
        $_ | Move-Item -Destination $destination
    }
```

Regex details:

```
^                 Assert position at the beginning of the string
(?:               Match the regular expression below
    \[            Match the character “[” literally
    \w            Match a single character that is a “word character” (letters, digits, etc.)
        +         Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
    \]            Match the character “]” literally
){3}              Exactly 3 times
(?:               Match the regular expression below
    \[            Match the character “[” literally
    (             Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
        \w        Match a single character that is a “word character” (letters, digits, etc.)
            +     Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
    )
    \]            Match the character “]” literally
)
```

P.S. The error you received is rather clear I think.. `$fileName.lastIndexOf("]")` returns the 0-based **index** position of the last square bracket in the string. The second parameter for `Substring()` should be the **Length** of the substring to take from the string, not an index value.